Proving the sum of the squares of numbers which sum to $1$ has a lower bound of $\frac{1}{n}$.
Given $\sum^n_{i=1}\rho_i=1$, I need to prove that $$\sum^n_{i=1}\rho_i^2 \in \left[ \frac{1}{n}, 1\right].$$ The upper bound is clear, and I know the lower bound is obtainable by setting all the $\rho_i$ to $\frac{1}{n}$, but I can't seem to prove it algebraically.
I think an inductive proof, with a base case of $n=2$ is the way forward but I keep getting stuck.
Can anyone help?

To get $\sum \rho_i^2 \le 1$ you need each $0\le \rho_i \le 1$ (as for a probability), in which case $\rho_i^2 \le \rho_i$ and so $\sum \rho_i^2 \le \sum \rho_i=1$

To get the lower bound, you might use $x^2+y^2= \left(\frac{x+y}2\right)^2+\left(\frac{x+y}2\right)^2 + \frac{(x-y)^2}2$ and so the minimum must occur when all the $\rho_i$s are equal

Notice that:$$n=\sum_{i=1}^n1^2$$
Using Cauchy inequality:$$(\sum_{i=1}^n1^2)(\sum^n_{i=1}\rho_i^2)\geq(\sum^n_{i=1}\rho_i)^2$$

There is a well-known inequality between the arithmetic mean $\frac{a_1+ \ldots + a_n}{n}$ and the quadratic mean $\sqrt{\frac{a_1^2+\ldots +a_n^2}{n}}$ for nonnegative numbers $a_i$, namely that the quadratic mean is greater than or equal to the arithmetic mean (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QM-AM-GM-HM_inequalities). Applying that elementary inequality gives exactly the bound you are looking for.
The inequality is a special case of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality (namely where one of the vectors is simply $(1,1,\ldots,1)$), which you can prove by induction, so that was not a bad idea on your part. However, conditions like the sum of your variables being equal to 1 make directly applying induction more complicated. It should still work, but it might be better to take away from this that there exists some inequality relating the sum of $n$ numbers to the sum of their squares.

Lagrange multipliers suggests a good way to do this. Since $ L = \sum_i ( \rho_i^2 - \lambda \rho_i ) + \lambda $ is a convex function, it has a unique minimum, so all we have to do is find it. We have
$$ \frac{\partial L}{\partial \rho_i} = 2\rho_i - \lambda , $$
so for this to vanish, all the $\rho_i$ are equal. For the $\lambda$ derivative to vanish, we have to satisfy the constraint $ \sum_i \rho_i = 1 $, and combining this with the other equations, the $\rho_i$ are all equal to $1/n$.
Personally I think this is neater, but it does use calculus.

I don't understand this method; wouldn't $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda} = \sum_i -\rho_i = -1$?

Sorry, I forgot to include the constant, now $\partial L / \partial \lambda = 1 - \sum_i \rho_i$, which is zero when the constraint $ \sum_i \rho_i = 1$ is satisfied.

Got it! Thank you :)
